# HOG Detection training with CvSVM

Tags: opencv, svm

I've been looking everywhere, and I cannot find any good tutorials on training a `HOGDescriptor`. I'm a beginner with HOG, but I have used other object detection algorithms before (e.g. `CascadeClassifier`).

The way I see it, I have to create a `CvSVM` object and run `CvSVM::train()`, passing in a vector of vectors of floats (Mat), the labels (1 or -1) for that Mat, and a `CvSVMParams` object. I am very confused as to how to then convert that CvSVM to a vector of floats that is required in the `HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector()`. I am aware that I can use `CvSVM::predict()`, but that doesn't allow me to do multi-scale detection. Is there any code available that I could pass in my trained `CvSVM` (or possibly the original vector of vectors) and get a vector of floats to use to train my `HOGDescriptor`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply build your own multiscale detector by running `CvSVM::predict()` on multiple scales of the same image assuming the fact that you had the same scales in your training set.